# Xamarin Maps on android custom pins query

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am working on a xamarin forms app using xamarin forms maps for Android at the moment that tracks my location and depending on my proximity to a custom pin i have placed on the map will change in size depending on my proximity.
Basically if within a few meters the icon is 32x32 and farther away its 24x24.
Ive created a custom map renderer that places my pins from a JSON file and this is ok.
When my map form page loads in both my simulator and an actual android device the methods run and get my proximity based on my location and appropriately alter the size of the map pin.
However, this does not work as i move around.
For some reason my overridden CreateMarker method does not trigger when my location changes unless i call Content=customMap. Doing this only causes my map to load over and over and basically will not work.
I have a method in my about page called UpdateMap3() that is called when the users location changes. However, as stated i cant get the pins to update their size as i get nearer the pins while the app is running.

Ive included my forms page code behind below and markup below that and finally my map renderer below that.
Any help would be hugely appreciated.
Thanls

```
    using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Distance = Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Distance;
using Google.Protobuf.WellKnownTypes;
using static Google.Protobuf.Reflection.FieldDescriptorProto.Types;

namespace MAPS.Views
{
    public partial class AboutPage : ContentPage
    {
        IlocationUpdateService loc;
     
        public AboutPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
          //  Task.Delay(2000);
          UpdateMap();
        }
        async void OnActionSheetCancelDeleteClicked()
        {
            bool answer = await DisplayAlert("Location Request", "Please enable location services to use this app", "Settings", "Cancel");
            if (answer == true)
            {
                DependencyService.Get<ILocSettings>().OpenSettings();
            }
        }
        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            bool gpsStat = DependencyService.Get<ILocSettings>().isGpsAvailable();
            if (gpsStat == false)
            {
                OnActionSheetCancelDeleteClicked();
            }

            loc = DependencyService.Get<IlocationUpdateService>();

            loc.LocationChanged += (object sender, ILocationEventArgs args) =>
              {

                     String lat1 = args.Latitude.ToString();
                    String lng1 = args.Longitude.ToString();
                  //String lat1 = "55.099300";
                  // String lng1 = "-8.279740";
                  UpdateMap3(lat1, lng1); ;
              };
            loc.GetUsedLocation();
  
        }
        
        protected override void OnDisappearing()
        {
            base.OnDisappearing();
            loc = null;

        }
        List<Place> placesList = new List<Place>();
        private async void UpdateMap()
        {
            var assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(AboutPage)).Assembly;
                Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MAPS.Places.json");
                string text = string.Empty;
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    text = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
                var resultObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Places>(text);
                var request = new Xamarin.Essentials.GeolocationRequest(GeolocationAccuracy.Best, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
                var location = await Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(request);
            CustomMap customMap = new CustomMap()
            {
                IsShowingUser = true

            };
            customMap.CustomPins = new List<CustomPin>(); // put this before the foreach

            foreach (var place in resultObject.results)
            {
                Location location1 = new Location(place.geometry.location.lat,place.geometry.location.lng);
              //  string color = getDist(location1, location);
              string  color = "purple";
                if (color == "purple")
                {
                    CustomPin pin = new CustomPin()
                    {

                        Type = PinType.Place,
                        Position = new Position(place.geometry.location.lat, place.geometry.location.lng),
                        Label = place.id,
                        Address = place.vicinity+"*",
                        Name = "Xamarin",
                        icon = "icon.png",
                        Url = "http://xamarin.com/about/"
                    };

                    customMap.Pins.Add(pin);
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    CustomPin pin = new CustomPin()
                    {

                        Type = PinType.Place,
                        Position = new Position(place.geometry.location.lat, place.geometry.location.lng),
                        Label = place.id,
                        Address = place.vicinity,
                        Name = "Xamarin",
                        icon = "pin.png",
                        Url = "http://xamarin.com/about/"
                    };

                    customMap.Pins.Add(pin);
                  
                }
            }
                customMap.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(location.Latitude, location.Longitude), Distance.FromKilometers(0.15))); ;
            Content = customMap;
  }
        public string getDist(Location loc, Xamarin.Essentials.Location currentLoc)
        {
            string color = "red";
            //  bool geo = false;
            double latEnd = loc.lat;
            double lngEnd = loc.lng;
            ///  Position(currentLoc.lat, currentLoc.lng);
            double dist = currentLoc.CalculateDistance(latEnd, lngEnd, DistanceUnits.Kilometers);
            if (dist < 0.05) //5m distance
            {

                color = "purple";



            }
            else
            {
                color = "red";
            }
            return color;
        }
        public void getNewPins()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
 public void getPin()
        {
            var pr = new PopUp();
        }


        private async void UpdateMap3(String lat, String lng)
        {
            var assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(AboutPage)).Assembly;
            Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MAPS.Places.json");
            string text = string.Empty;
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                text = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            var resultObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Places>(text);
        
            CustomMap customMap = new CustomMap()
            {
                IsShowingUser = true

            };

            customMap.CustomPins = new List<CustomPin>(); // put this before the foreach

            foreach (var place in resultObject.results)
            {
                Location location1 = new Location(place.geometry.location.lat, place.geometry.location.lng);
                Xamarin.Essentials.Location location = new Xamarin.Essentials.Location(Convert.ToDouble(lat), Convert.ToDouble(lng));
                string color = getDist(location1, location);

                if (color == "purple")
                {
                    CustomPin pin2 = new CustomPin()
                    {

                        Type = PinType.Place,
                        Position = new Position(place.geometry.location.lat, place.geometry.location.lng),
                        Label = place.id,
                        Address = place.vicinity,
                        Name = "Xamarin",
                        icon = "icon.png",
                        Url = "http://xamarin.com/about/"
                    };
                    customMap.CustomPins = new List<CustomPin> {pin2};                  
                    customMap.Pins.Add(pin2);
    
                }
                else
                {
                    CustomPin pin2 = new CustomPin()
                    {

                        Type = PinType.Place,
                        Position = new Position(place.geometry.location.lat, place.geometry.location.lng),
                        Label = place.id,
                        Address = place.vicinity+"*",
                        Name = "Xamarin",
                        icon = "pin.png",
                        Url = "http://xamarin.com/about/"
                    };
                    customMap.CustomPins = new List<CustomPin> { pin2 };
                    customMap.Pins.Add(pin2);
                  //  Content.IsEnabled = true;
                    // customMap.CustomPins.Remove(pin);
                }
            }
            //   customMap.Pins.Clear();


            //   customMap.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(Convert.ToDouble(lat), Convert.ToDouble(lng)), Distance.FromKilometers(0.15))); ;
          //  Content = customMap;

           // customMap.Pins.Add(pins);
        }
  }
    }
```

Below is my forms page markup.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MAPS;assembly=MAPS"
             x:Class="MAPS.Views.AboutPage"  Title="Explore">
  
    <StackLayout>
    
        <local:CustomMap x:Name="customMap" IsShowingUser="True"
                     MapType="Street" />
    

    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Below is my Android custom renderer

```
    using Android.Content;
using Android.Gms.Maps;
using Android.Gms.Maps.Model;
using Android.Widget;
using MAPS;
using MAPS.Droid;
using MAPS.Views;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Rg.Plugins.Popup;
using Rg.Plugins.Popup.Animations;
using Rg.Plugins.Popup.Contracts;
using Rg.Plugins.Popup.Enums;
using Rg.Plugins.Popup.Services;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Android;
using static MAPS.Droid.CustomMapRenderer;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomMap), typeof(CustomMapRenderer))]

namespace MAPS.Droid
{

    public class CustomMapRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Android.MapRenderer, GoogleMap.IInfoWindowAdapter
    {
        List<CustomPin> customPins;
        public string popInfo;
        public CustomMapRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs<Map> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                NativeMap.InfoWindowClick -= OnInfoWindowClick;
            }

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                var formsMap = (CustomMap)e.NewElement;
                customPins = formsMap.CustomPins;
                Control.GetMapAsync(this);
            }
        }
        protected override void OnMapReady(GoogleMap map)
        {
            base.OnMapReady(map);

            NativeMap.InfoWindowClick += OnInfoWindowClick;
            NativeMap.SetInfoWindowAdapter(this);
         
        }

        protected override MarkerOptions CreateMarker(Pin pin)
        {
            var marker = new MarkerOptions();
            
       //     CustomPin p = new CustomPin();
            //foreach (var cp in customPins)
            //{
            //    if (cp.Position == pin.Position)
            //    {
            //        p = cp;
            //    }
            //}
            marker.SetPosition(new LatLng(pin.Position.Latitude, pin.Position.Longitude));
            marker.SetTitle(pin.Label);
         
            // marker.SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromFile(p.icon));
            if (pin.Address.Contains('*'))
            {
                marker.SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.pin2));
            }
            else
            {
                marker.SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.pin));
            }
            marker.Visible(true);
            var a = NativeMap.AddMarker(marker);
                 a.ShowInfoWindow();



            //  marker.SetSnippet(pin.Address.Replace("*", " "));
            return marker;
        }

        void OnInfoWindowClick(object sender, GoogleMap.InfoWindowClickEventArgs e)
        {

            getPlaceData(markerdata.markerData.title, markerdata.markerData.lat, markerdata.markerData.lng);
            showPopUp();


        }
    

        public Android.Views.View GetInfoContents(Marker marker)
        {


            return null;
        }
        public void  myMod(Marker marker)
        {

        }

        public Android.Views.View GetInfoWindow(Marker marker)
        {
            markerdata.markerData.title = marker.Title;

            markerdata.markerData.lat = marker.Position.Latitude.ToString("0.#####");
            markerdata.markerData.lng = marker.Position.Longitude.ToString("0.#####");
            // ds.Id = marker.Id;
        //    getPlaceData(marker.Title, marker.Position.Latitude.ToString("0.#####"), marker.Position.Longitude.ToString("0.#####"));
         //   showPopUp();
       








            return null;
        }

        public string Number;
     
        private async void showPopUp()
        {
          
            var Pr = new Views.PopUp();
            var scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation
            {
                PositionIn = MoveAnimationOptions.Right,
                PositionOut = MoveAnimationOptions.Left
            };

            Pr.Animation = scaleAnimation;

            await PopupNavigation.PushAsync(Pr);

        }
        CustomPin GetCustomPin(Marker annotation)
        {

            return null;
        }
        private void getPlaceData(String name, String Lat, String Lng)
        {
            var assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(AboutPage)).Assembly;
            Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MAPS.Places.json");
            string text = string.Empty;
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                text = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            var resultObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Places>(text);

            foreach (var place in resultObject.results)
            {
                if((name==place.id)&&(Lat ==place.geometry.location.lat.ToString("0.#####"))&&(Lng ==place.geometry.location.lng.ToString("0.#####")))
                {
                    getData.Instance.Id = place.id;
                    getData.Instance.lat = place.geometry.location.lat.ToString("0.#####");
                    getData.Instance.lng = place.geometry.location.lng.ToString("0.#####");
                    getData.Instance.marker2 = place.name;
                    getData.Instance.family = place.family;
                   getData.Instance.origin = place.Origin;
                    getData.Instance.date = place.Date;
                    getData.Instance.commonName = place.CommonName;
                //    getData.Instance.title = marker.Title;
             
                }

            }

        }
    }
      
}
```

Comment: I believe the pins are cached so they are not having to constantly regenerate them.  Any pin that you want to change probably needs to be remove and readded as you pan

Comment: Hello, I was thinking that but the createMarker function doesnt fire for me, even if i pins.clear or pins.remove it doesnt appear to do anything. I am just not sure why i cant run the cratemarker function in my custom renderer when i call pins.add. Seems i am missing something, just not sure what.

Comment: More details about what Jason said: You'll need an update method that is called as you move around. It needs to go through all your pins, any that need to change, you have to *remove* and ***re-add***.  You have to **manually add** those pins again; currently there is no logic telling `createMarker` to run, because as you move, there are no pins being added. (If you figure out how to do so, please add an answer below, so everyone will know how this should be done.)